# Blowfish in C# from Java

Tags: c#, java, encryption

Is there anything in c# already out there with an example of doing the same thing like this in Java.  I am trying the below code.  Does the encryption look right?  It has a bunch of ? marks in it.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("BlowFish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
        string keyHex = Hex.ToHexString(keyBytes); //4b334c33315551354f38325059344739

        string parameters = "{\"userId\":\"6440870\"}";
        byte[] parametersByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
        string parametersHex = Hex.ToHexString(parametersByte); //7b22757365724964223a2236343430383730227d

        BlowFish bl = new BlowFish(keyHex);
        byte[] outputEncryptedByte = bl.Encrypt_ECB(parametersByte);
        string outputEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputEncryptedByte); //7lC[t$?mQd?g???kE?W?[?
        string outputBase64 = System.Convert.
```

ToBase64String(outputEncryptedByte); //N2xDW3Qk/xgObVFkpmfBgchrRepXnVu9

Comment: I don't think there is any thing in .net framework but check out [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)

Comment: I have.  Not much experience in the encryption department.

Answer (score 2):

Its not implemented in Framework but you can get an Implementation in C# from here

http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html

just put that code in a .cs file in your project directory and use it like this.

```
BlowFish b = new BlowFish("04B915BA43FEB5B6");
string plainText = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
string cipherText = b.Encrypt_CBC(plainText);
MessageBox.Show(cipherText);
plainText = b.Decrypt_CBC(cipherText);
MessageBox.Show(plainText);
```

Comment: Does that include the PKCS5 padding?

Comment: I updated what I am trying to do.  Does the encryption output look ok?

Answer (score 0):

One more implementation of BlowFish in Java -- http://dexxtr.com/post/57145943236/blowfish-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-java-android

```
private byte[] encrypt(String key, String plainText) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    SecretKey secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITM);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key);

    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```